# Test an app in django and connect to local database

Tags: python, django

How can I test my app in django, so that it connects to my local database and does NOT require me to create a test database?

Comment: Please show what you have done so far...

Comment: if you want to do testing you have simply to define a mirror of your existing DB in the setting.py

Answer (score 0):

Can't you specify the details of your development database in settings.py? This would connect you to the existing database and remove the need to create a new test instance.